# Ito integral via simple process when the integrand is C^1

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, simple-functions

I have the following problem. Let $H_t$ be an adapted process with trajectories a.s. of class $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$. Compute using simple process $\int_o^t H_s d B_s$.

My idea is to firstly set $U_n(s):=\sum_{i=0}^{m(n)-1} H_{t_i^n} \mathbb{1}_{(t_i^n-t_{i+1}^n]}$ (where of course I considered a partition of $[0,t]$) and show that this sequence of simple processes tends to $H_s$. This allows me to say that the sequence of the integrals of $U_n$ converges to the integral of $H_s$. Then, computing the integral of $U_n$ (as n $\to \infty$) we conclude.

Now, in showing that $U_n \to H_s$ I am note sure whether I can state the following : since $H_t$ is a.s. of class $C_1$ on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$, then

$|H_{t_i^n}-H_s| \leq M |t_i^n-s|$

for some constant $M$. I would say it holds thanks to Lagrange's theorem ($\omega$ per $\omega$) but Lagrange requires a function to be continuos on a closed set and differentiable on the open.

Thank you very much for any help :)

Comment: Have you tried to integrate by parts or equivalently rewriting your integral sum in such a way, that you get increments of $H$?